# Headers getting added to file content while retrieving file from APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent in AWS lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS Lambda to push the file to S3 through Java code.
While sending the file from Postman or from Angular I am trying to print the content of file in Java functions. While doing so headers are getting added to the file content automatically like:

```
"----------------------------965855468995803568737630
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"; filename="test.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf"
```

.

How to get the file content without headers from APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent?.

This is code am using to print the file content.

```
context.getLogger().log("Input File: "+apiGatewayProxyRequestEvent.getBody());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one for you to solve. The method `getBody()` will give you the actual request body that is sent through the `APIGatewayProxyRequest` so it's going to give you back what is sent through, which is the file encoded as form-data with a Content-Type and a filename. The responsibility lies on you to convert the form-data back into an understandable object format if you wan to print the content.

If you have a look at this [tutorial on Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/processing-multipart-form-data-using-api-gateway-and-a-java-lambda-proxy-for-storage-in-s3-e6598033ff3e) you can see an approach to this. It boils down to processing the data and working with the format boundary:

```
//Get the uploaded file and decode from base64 
      byte[] bI = Base64.decodeBase64(event.getBody().getBytes()); 
      //Get the content-type header and extract the boundary 
      Map<String, String> hps = event.getHeaders(); 
      if (hps != null) { 
        contentType = hps.get("content-type"); 
      } 
      String[] boundaryArray = contentType.split("="); 
      //Transform the boundary to a byte array 
      byte[] boundary = boundaryArray[1].getBytes(); 
      //Log the extraction for verification purposes 
      logger.log(new String(bI, "UTF-8") + "\n");
```

That last line will get you what you want, which is printing the body content, obviously if it's a binary format that might not be very useful for you. I'd recommend giving that tutorial a full read as it will help show you how to iterate through the data stream and create the object.